# Check if mysql scheduler event already exists

Tags: php, mysql

I have a cron job that crawls a website every 15 mins and returns information on a number of entries. I have an ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE statement to deal with whether to insert or update an entry. I want to add a scheduled event to each new insert giving it an expiration time.

Is there a way to check to see if an event already exists that I can check for and assign or not based on the result? Or will I have to break up my INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE statement to where I check for the rows existence, and then INSERT and add the scheduled event if it doesn't exist?

Comment: I read this thrice and still don't know what you mean by "Is there a way to check to see if an event already exists that I can check for and assign or not based on the result". Can you explain that a bit better? Why doesn't `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` work?

Comment: Yeah that sentence is pretty awkward, sorry. The ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE works fine for me, but I want to assign a "mysql event scheduler" event for each of the new entries in order to expire them eventually. So what I want to check for is if there is a "mysql event scheduler" event that exists for an entry already, and if not, assign one. I know the events must have unique names, but I can't seem to find how to check if an event of a certain name exists already.

Comment: Why not just add an expiration `DATETIME` column and then do `DELETE FROM yourtable WHERE expiration < NOW()` before you do your insert?

Comment: @Mike Because I only update the table at 15 minute increments but I want the rows to expire at the precise time that they are supposed to, down to the second.

Comment: You probably don't have to do it like that. When you do your `SELECT`s  just do `SELECT ... FROM yourtable WHERE expiration > NOW()` and it will ignore all entries where expiration `<= NOW()`. You don't actually have to worry about the rows being deleted. Then just set up a cron job/scheduled task every day or so that will clean up the old entries.